# Range operator in Groovy not printing entire range of numbers

Tags: groovy

New to groovy and following tutorial on Tutorialspoint and got stuck on range operators [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_operators.htm)

Under range operators, notation provided is `def range = 0..5`

The code snipped they used to show an example

```
class Example {
  static void main(String[] args) {
    def range = 5..10;
    println(range);
    println(range.get(2));
  }
}
```

Output should be

```
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
7
```

Executing that same snipped I am getting

```
5..10
7
```

I tried that example and removing semicolons but get the same result. Could you explain what am I doing wrong here, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're expecting a list in your first print

If you have to, you can do

```
println range.toList()
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is printing the `IntRange` object you're creating with `5..10`. You can see that IntRange's [`toString()`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_5_6/src/main/groovy/groovy/lang/IntRange.java#L359) will print exactly what you're getting.

To print each of the items in the range, you'd need to use a loop.

```
range.each {
    println it
}
```

However, that won't give you the exact output you're looking for as each number will be on its own line.